# Undefined method Zip::ZipOutputStream.write_buffer on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, zip, sinatra, rubyzip

I'm making a basic Sinatra app to play around with the [Passbook](https://github.com/frozon/passbook) gem.

My app runs fine on `localhost`, but when I try and run it on Heroku I get this error message:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/passbook-0.2.1/lib/passbook/pkpass.rb:122:in `outputZip'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/passbook-0.2.1/lib/passbook/pkpass.rb:60:in `stream'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1593:in `call'
NoMethodError - undefined method `write_buffer' for Zip::ZipOutputStream:Class:
```

This happens when I call the line `passbook.stream.string` in my app file.

I don't think Passbook is the problem here - it seems that the class method `write_buffer` exists in the version of `Zip::ZipOutputStream` on my local machine but isn't there on Heroku. Why is this? How can I get around it?

I've tried including both `zip` and `rubyzip` in my Gemfile, individually and at the same time, and neither of them solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I see something like this, I always ask myself [Do you have Dev/Prod parity?](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/development-configuration#dev-prod-parity).

So:

- What Ruby version do you use locally, and does it differ from what you're using on Heroku?
- Do you specify a Ruby version in your Gemfile?
- How do you run locally?  Do you use `bundle exec` to ensure you run in the same way, with the same gems?

Comment: Turns out I was using ruby 1.9.3 locally and 2.0.0 on Heroku. Fixing this didn't solve my problem. But when I run my app with `bundle exec`  I get the same error locally that I do on Heroku! A step backward, but it gives me more information about the error I suppose.

Comment: Excellent - glad to have helped!  Now it's probably down to the Gemfile and the right version of the Gem etc.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.

When I ran `ruby app.rb`, things worked locally, but when I ran `bundle exec ruby app.rb`, I got the same error as I did on heroku.

I upgraded to the latest version of passbook (which was just updated [today](https://github.com/frozon/passbook/pull/28) to handle the latest changes to rubyzip), but things still didn't work.

Turns out I needed to remove `gem 'zip'` from my Gemfile and just include `gem 'rubyzip'` - previously I had both.